# Find Closest Value In Subset of Range

Tags: excel, lookup

I have data with two columns A and B.  I need a formula to find the value in column B which is closest to a input value where the corresponding value in column A equals a second input value.

For example, here is some sample data

```
Col A   Col B
12.5    0.4
12.5    0.69
12.5    0.75
18      0.5
18      0.695
18      0.4
20      0.2
20      0.8
20      0.71
```

Let's say my input value for A is 12.5 and my input value for B is 0.7.  The formula would return the value 0.69 because that is the number which is closest to 0.7 in the subset of data where Col A equals 12.5.

If I change input A to 18 and leave input B to 0.7 the formula should return 0.695.

For an input of A = 20 and B = 0.7 the formula would return 0.71

Is this making sense?

I know the following formula can be used to find a value closest to another value.

```
=INDEX(rng,MATCH(MIN(ABS(rng-value)),ABS(rng-value),0))
```

And I know you can use SUMPRODUCT to search on multiple criteria.  I just can't figure out how to put it all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your values are in `A1:B9`, then use:

```
=INDEX(B1:B9,MATCH(MIN(ABS(IF(A1:A9=12.5,B1:B9)-0.7)),ABS(IF(A1:A9=12.5,B1:B9)-0.7),0))
```

This is an *array formula*, so type the formula then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Curly brackets will automatically appear at the start and end of the formula.

Or another approach (returns min from closest):

```
=MIN(IF(MIN(ABS(IF(A1:A9=12.5,B1:B9)-0.7))=ABS(IF(A1:A9=12.5,B1:B9)-0.7),B1:B9))
```

also with array entry (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>)